# Automate "Attach to Process" in VS2005/2008

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I was wondering if anyone knew of a macro or keyboard shortcut or anything really that would automate Attaching to a Process within visual studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`

"If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a debugger. If yes, the debugger is started. If a debugger is attached, the debugger is signaled with a user breakpoint event, and the debugger suspends execution of the process just as if a debugger breakpoint had been hit."

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx

Answer (score 10):

`CTRL + ALT + P` brings up the dialog box. Then hit the first letter of the process you want to attach to, e.g. `W` for w3wp.exe

Comment: I just found this too... in combination with the above will give me pretty much everything I need :)

Answer (score 2):

The macro is described in post [Attach to Process with one shortcut](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/01/11/Attach-to-Process-with-one-shortcut.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can just record a macro and assign a keyboard shortcut to it in the options dialog. That's what I did. I press CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-Z and it attaches to aspnet_wp.exe for me.